# Why .Net MVC (.Net 4.8) do not show static methods API in API Explorer / Help page?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-apiexplorer

I have this API,

```
    [HttpPut]
    [CustomExceptionFilter]
    [Route("api/Port/SetExternalEngineLights")]
    public string SetExternalEngineLights()
    {
        return "...something"
    }
```

It then will show up in help page,
[image]

But if I set the method to be `static`, the method disappeared from help page.

```
    [HttpPut]
    [CustomExceptionFilter]
    [Route("api/Port/SetExternalEngineLights")]
    public static string SetExternalEngineLights()
    {
        return "...something"
    }
```

Google yield no meaningful results. Are there any fix or workaround?

Comment: I wouldn't expect a `static` method to be considered part of the API interface exposed by that controller object.  This sounds like correct and expected behavior to me.  Turning the question around... Why do you *want* to make the method `static`?  What actual problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @David Apart from calling the API from URLs, I wanted to call the API's method from the code base itself. Making the method `static` can let me call this method without initializing the controller class. What's the alternatives? I, for now, call the method like this: `new APIController().SetExternalEngineLights()`

Comment: Don't just sprinkle the `static` keyword around the code to "make things easier".  You'll find this ends up making things *much* more difficult as complexity grows, particularly when it comes to testability.  If you *need* to call a controller method then, ideally, the controllers are injectable by the dependency injection like anything else.  But, taking a step back, you probably don't need or want to call a controller method like that.  If the controller is invoking a business operation that needs to be more common, refactor it into a business object/service that can be used anywhere.

Comment: @David Thanks for the valuable insight. I'll try to refactor some codes and structures.